# Getting Memory Consumption using C API in Z3 Solver

Tags: z3

When I used `-st` flag in Z3, I get the memory consumption of Z3.
However, I would like to get the same using the `C/C++ API`. Could someone tell how to do it? I tried to use the API `Z3_solver_get_statistics()` and then `Z3_stats_to_string()`. However the resulting string does not contain any information about memory.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not exposed in the Z3 API. You can obtain this information by using the method

```
static unsigned long long get_allocation_size();
```

in the class `memory`. This method is defined in the file `src/util/memory_manager.h`.
The idea is to add a new function in the Z3 API that returns this value.
If you are using Z3 static library, I believe you can directly access this method by including the `memory_manager.h`.